# How can I programatically do fake payment in payu sandbox?

Tags: python, testing, payu

I have django oscar application which use PayU as a payment provider. I'm writing tests, to test my refund mechanism. So I am using sandbox service for do such things. I have created test, which place request to PayU "create order". Then I got a redirect url, where I can (in browser) do fake payment using my bank account. But in test, I would like to do it programatically. I read whole documentation, but I didn't find such option. On SoF there is no similar questions. PayU support didn't aswer my question(they have 24h).

I'm wondering if there is possibility to post proper form to proper url on payu - but after quick html review I think it may be tricky.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After reading documentation I have found sollution.
First of all, I should not use "pay with bank account". 
I should use "pay with credit/debit card".

And in payu documentation there is information which data use to complete payment programatically (by sending POST data).

Answer (score -1):

Refer to below link for the documentation of PayU refund:
https://documentation.payubiz.in/refunds/

Comment: Before sending refund, I would like to do fake payment.

Comment: One way to do test payment is to  post your form to payu server with all mandatory details, then PayU will redirect to a page where you can enter test credit/debit card details. After filling the details, PayU will post transaction details on your server successUrl.